# Hola quisiera saber porque el formulario (en java) muestra los datos en null

Tags: java

```
//Aquí guardo los datos ingresados por teclado
private void botonGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        if (txtNombre.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor ingrese el nombre");
            return;
        }
        if (txtApellidos.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor ingrese los apellidos");
            return;
        }
        if (txtRut.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor ingrese el RUT");
            return;
        }
        if (txtValidador.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor ingrese el código validador");
            return;
        }
        if (txtEmail.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor ingrese el email");
            return;
        }
        if (txtTelefono.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor ingrese el teléfono");
            return;
        }

        String Nombre, Apellidos, Rut, Email, Telefono;

        Nombre = txtNombre.getText();
        Apellidos = txtApellidos.getText();
        Rut = txtRut.getText();
        Email = txtEmail.getText();
        Telefono = txtTelefono.getText();

        Persona persona = new Persona(Nombre, Apellidos, Rut, Email, Telefono);
        agenda.GuardarPersona(persona);

//Se guardan en esta agenda
public class Agenda {

    Vector vector = new Vector();
    Persona persona = new Persona();

    public void GuardarPersona(Persona persona) {

        if (vector.add(persona)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha agregado correctamente la persona");
        }
    }

//Y finalmente llamo a este metodo pero los datos me salen en null

    public String MostrarAgenda() {
        String Linea = "", Linea2;

        for (int x = 0; x < vector.size(); x++) {
            persona = (Persona) vector.get(x);
            Linea2 =" Nombre: "+ persona.Nombre + " \n " +"Apellido.: "+ persona.Apellidos + " \n " +"Rut.........: "+ persona.Rut + " \n "+"Telefono: " + persona.Telefono;

            Linea = Linea + Linea2 + "\n";
        }
        return Linea;
    }

}
```

---

@Franco Rolando imagino que te refieres a esta clase

```
public class Persona {

    public String Nombre;
    public String Apellidos;
    public String Rut;
    public String Telefono;

    public Persona() {

    }

    public Persona(String Nombre, String Apellidos, String Rut, String Email, String Telefono) {
```

Comment: String Nombre, Apellidos, Rut, Email, Telefono; Tienes declaradas las variables con mayusculas al inicio, solo las clases empiezan con mayusculas al inicio! Fijate en la clase persona, en su constructor si estas asignando los valores por parametro a los atributos ya que no hay codigo de eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Sirvio mio respuesta? marcala como tema solucionado! saludos

Comment: Si, gracias. Ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya está solucionado, debía inicializar, me faltaba agregar esto:

```
    nombre=Nombre;
    apellidos=Apellidos;
    rut=Rut;
    telefono=Telefono;

}
```

Gracias, esta es mi primera pregunta en stack overflow, no se como puntuar, ni siquiera tengo reputación para comentar. Saludos

Comment: cuando puedas, junto a la respuesta te saldrá una V verde. Púlsala para dar como válida tu respuesta. Para dar puntos a una respuesta o para valorar un comentario, simplemente tiene que pulsar las flechas que hay al lado de la respuesta o comentario, hacia arriba voto positivo, hacia abajo negativo. Ánimo y bienvenido a SOes =).

Comment: Ok, lo harè gracias.

Answer (score 0):

puedo ver que hiciste el mismo programa con el que actualmente tengo problemas. ¿Cómo solucionaste el error de que `agenda.GuardarPersona(persona);` y `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,agenda.MostrarAgenda());` el termino agenda no aparece en verde?. Desconozco que agregar.

De antemano, agradezco tu respuesta.

Comment: Hola, para que me apareciera la agenda en verde hice una instanciación de la clase Agenda, de este modo: Agenda agenda = new Agenda();    ... Eso lo escribi en la públic class de la interfaz donde tengo los eventos de los botones y eso. No se si me explique